# My python code refuses to run for this discord bot I am making

Tags: python, discord.py

## Nothing works or runs

## The client simply will not run and I get a blank console and I can not get the bot to respond in discord

I have ran the bot and it refuses to work 
It has stopped reponding to my text input in discord chat and will not respond to it

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from itertools import cycle

token = 'Dummy Token ACGT'
status = ['EpicGamerTime', 'Help', 'GamerStuff']
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ",")

@client.event   
async def on_ready(self):
    print('Logged in as')
    print(self.user.name)
    print(self.user.id)
    print('------')

async def change_status():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    statuses = cycle(status)
    while not client.is_closed:
        current_status = next(statuses)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=current_status))
        await asyncio.sleep(2) 

@client.event
async def on_message(self, message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author.id == self.user.id:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message))

    if message.content.startswith('!who is online'):
        await message.channel.send('Not Sure {0.author.mention}'.format(message))

    if message.content.endswith('whammy'):
        await message.channel.send('response {0.author.mention}'.format(message))



client.loop.create_task(change_status())
client.run(token)
```

## No output or error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed all `self`s from funcs and used `client` where `self` was used

Hope this helps

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from itertools import cycle
from toke import token

status = ['EpicGamerTime', 'Help', 'GamerStuff']
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=",")


@client.event   
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')


async def change_status():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    statuses = cycle(status)
    while not client.is_closed:
        current_status = next(statuses)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=current_status))
        await asyncio.sleep(2) 


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author.id == client.user.id:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message))

    if message.content.startswith('!who is online'):
        await message.channel.send('Not Sure {0.author.mention}'.format(message))

    if message.content.endswith('whammy'):
        await message.channel.send('response {0.author.mention}'.format(message))


client.loop.create_task(change_status())
client.run(token)
```

*BTW, pls don't post your token*

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you provide a short explanation for the changes you made to the code?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `self` as a variable in your functions. This is typically used when creating classes, which you are not doing.

Remove `self` from your functions and it works fine.

Also, I advise that you regenerate your bot token. Since you have included it in your question, anyone can use it to hijack your bot. Regenerate the token and do not share it with anyone.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from itertools import cycle

token = 'token'
status = ['EpicGamerTime', 'Help', 'GamerStuff']
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ",")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

async def change_status():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    statuses = cycle(status)
    while not client.is_closed:
        current_status = next(statuses)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=current_status))
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author.id == client.user.id:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message))

    if message.content.startswith('!who is online'):
        await message.channel.send('Not Sure {0.author.mention}'.format(message))

    if message.content.endswith('whammy'):
        await message.channel.send('response {0.author.mention}'.format(message))



client.loop.create_task(change_status())
client.run(token)
```